# Layers rendering incorrectly in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, jssor

I noticed that in the last year since I implemented the JJSOR slider, some update with IE has broken it in a number of their browsers.  Still works great in chrome, but in IE the div layer that is tweened breaks into pieces (different every time).

This is my latest code:

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title></title>
```

```
<!-- #region Jssor Slider Begin -->
<!-- Generator: Jssor Slider Maker -->
<!-- Source: https://www.jssor.com -->
<script src="js/jssor.slider-27.0.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jssor_1_slider_init = function() {

        var jssor_1_SlideoTransitions = [
          [{b:0,d:600,y:-244,e:{y:27}}],
          [{b:0,d:600,x:1156,e:{x:27}}],
          [{b:-1,d:1,o:-1},{b:0,d:600,o:1,e:{o:5}}],
          [{b:0,d:1000,y:116}]
        ];

        var jssor_1_options = {
          $AutoPlay: 1,
          $Idle: 6000,
          $FillMode: 4,
          $Cols: 1,
          $Align: 0,
          $CaptionSliderOptions: {
            $Class: $JssorCaptionSlideo$,
            $Transitions: jssor_1_SlideoTransitions
          },
          $ArrowNavigatorOptions: {
            $Class: $JssorArrowNavigator$
          },
          $BulletNavigatorOptions: {
            $Class: $JssorBulletNavigator$
          }
        };

        var jssor_1_slider = new $JssorSlider$("jssor_1", jssor_1_options);

        /*#region responsive code begin*/

        var MAX_WIDTH = 1200;

        function ScaleSlider() {
            var containerElement = jssor_1_slider.$Elmt.parentNode;
            var containerWidth = containerElement.clientWidth;

            if (containerWidth) {

                var expectedWidth = Math.min(MAX_WIDTH || containerWidth, containerWidth);

                jssor_1_slider.$ScaleWidth(expectedWidth);
            }
            else {
                window.setTimeout(ScaleSlider, 30);
            }
        }

        ScaleSlider();

        $Jssor$.$AddEvent(window, "load", ScaleSlider);
        $Jssor$.$AddEvent(window, "resize", ScaleSlider);
        $Jssor$.$AddEvent(window, "orientationchange", ScaleSlider);
        /*#endregion responsive code end*/
    };
</script>
<style>
    /* jssor slider bullet navigator skin 01 css */
    /*
    .jssorb01 div           (normal)
    .jssorb01 div:hover     (normal mouseover)
    .jssorb01 .av           (active)
    .jssorb01 .av:hover     (active mouseover)
    .jssorb01 .dn           (mousedown)
    */
    .jssorb01 {
        position: absolute;
    }
    .jssorb01 div, .jssorb01 div:hover, .jssorb01 .av {
        position: absolute;
        /* size of bullet elment */
        width: 12px;
        height: 12px;
        filter: alpha(opacity=70);
        opacity: .7;
        overflow: hidden;
        cursor: pointer;
        border: #000 1px solid;
    }
    .jssorb01 div { background-color: gray; }
    .jssorb01 div:hover, .jssorb01 .av:hover { background-color: #d3d3d3; }
    .jssorb01 .av { background-color: #fff; }
    .jssorb01 .dn, .jssorb01 .dn:hover { background-color: #555555; }

    /* jssor slider arrow navigator skin 03 css */
    /*
    .jssora03l                  (normal)
    .jssora03r                  (normal)
    .jssora03l:hover            (normal mouseover)
    .jssora03r:hover            (normal mouseover)
    .jssora03l.jssora03ldn      (mousedown)
    .jssora03r.jssora03rdn      (mousedown)
    */
    .jssora03l, .jssora03r {
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        /* size of arrow element */
        width: 55px;
        height: 55px;
        cursor: pointer;
        background: url('img/a03.png') no-repeat;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    .jssora03l { background-position: -3px -33px; }
    .jssora03r { background-position: -63px -33px; }
    .jssora03l:hover { background-position: -123px -33px; }
    .jssora03r:hover { background-position: -183px -33px; }
    .jssora03l.jssora03ldn { background-position: -243px -33px; }
    .jssora03r.jssora03rdn { background-position: -303px -33px; }
</style>

<div id="jssor_1" style="position:relative;margin:0 auto;top:0px;left:0px;width:1200px;height:444px;overflow:hidden;visibility:hidden;">
    <!-- Loading Screen -->
    <div data-u="loading" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.7);">
        <div style="filter: alpha(opacity=70); opacity: 0.7; position: absolute; display: block; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%;"></div>
        <div style="position:absolute;display:block;background:url('img/loading.gif') no-repeat center center;top:0px;left:0px;width:100%;height:100%;"></div>
    </div>
    <div data-u="slides" style="cursor:default;position:relative;top:0px;left:0px;width:1200px;height:444px;overflow:hidden;">
        <div data-p="205.50">
            <img data-u="image" src="img/002.jpg" />
            <div data-u="caption" data-t="0" style="position:absolute;top:320px;left:170px;width:350px;height:310px;background-color:rgba(187,205,255,0.2);font-size:18px;color:#0d0d0d;line-height:1.56;text-align:center;padding:8px 8px 8px 8px;box-sizing:border-box;">
               <h2><a href="burl_textures.html" class="h">First Header</a></h2>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
            </div>
        </div>
        <div data-p="205.50">
            <img data-u="image" src="img/003.jpg" />
            <div data-u="caption" data-t="1" style="position:absolute;top:46px;left:-380px;width:360px;height:265px;background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.5);font-size:18px;color:#303030;line-height:1.56;text-align:center;padding:8px 8px 8px 8px;box-sizing:border-box;">
                <h2><a href="burl_textures.html" class="h">Second Header</a></h2>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
            </div>
        </div>
        <div data-p="205.50">
            <img data-u="image" src="img/004.jpg" />
            <div data-u="caption" data-t="2" style="position:absolute;top:40px;left:750px;width:360px;height:265px;background-color:rgba(48,48,48,0.1);border-radius:1px;font-size:18px;color:#303030;line-height:1.56;text-align:center;padding:12px 12px 12px 12px;box-sizing:border-box;">
                <h2><a href="burl_textures.html" class="h">Third Header</a></h2>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
            </div>
        </div>
        <div data-p="205.50">
            <img data-u="image" src="img/007.jpg" />
            <div data-u="caption" data-t="3" style="position:absolute;top:-50px;left:56px;width:350px;height:70px;background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.5);font-size:18px;color:#303030;line-height:1.39;text-align:center;">
                <h2>Fourth Header</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Bullet Navigator -->
    <div data-u="navigator" class="jssorb01" style="bottom:12px;right:12px;">
        <div data-u="prototype" style="width:12px;height:12px;"></div>
    </div>
    <!-- Arrow Navigator -->
    <span data-u="arrowleft" class="jssora03l" style="top:0px;left:30px;width:55px;height:55px;" data-autocenter="2"></span>
    <span data-u="arrowright" class="jssora03r" style="top:0px;right:30px;width:55px;height:55px;" data-autocenter="2"></span>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">jssor_1_slider_init();</script>
<!-- #endregion Jssor Slider End -->
```

And here are some examples of the strange results I'm getting.  I'm pretty sure this has to do with IE's poor rendering of fluid objects, but I've tried just about everything to fix this and can't isolate the issue.

[image]

I'd greatly appreciate any thoughts on this. Thanks.

Comment: That's weird. Using your code, I can't see any difference between chrome and IE.

Comment: That's strange, the version info for Microsoft Edge I have on this laptop is Microsoft Edge 41.16299.15.0.  It definitely shows broken/disjointed background on any of the layers that tween.  I also tried viewing the "preview" of my slider at JSSOR.com in that browser, and it also had the same problems.

Comment: I see. I have no image at my end, I can't see the exact difference. If possible, please leave me the url of your slider.

Comment: We fixed the problem for Edge, and published version 27.0.4. Please let use know if the problem is still there.

Comment: @jssor The fix in the new version works for the tweened layers.  Unfortunately, something is causing the background layers to render differently. They look almost blurry or slightly opaque.  I sent you a chat message with more details as well.  Any idea what is causing this change with the new version?